# Dockerfile build RUN cmd fails but works from interactive

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running into an issue where building a Dockerfile fails at a 'make' command but if I run -it the container and make again it succeeds. Specifically the make command seems to be not seeing a file:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libcuda.so, needed by bin/gpu-example-alpha_comp. Stop.
```

But this is based on nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel and libcuda.so is there, i.e. if I run -it the container:

```
root@cf5637b85467:/opt/opencv/opencv/build# ll /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libcuda*.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 999 999 17 Nov 21 20:42 /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libcuda.so -> libcuda.so.370.28
lrwxrwxrwx 1 999 999 17 Nov 21 20:42 /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.370.28
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 8219624 Sep 2 02:25 /usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libcuda.so.370.28
```

and make completes without issue if I manually run it (I tried running from both /bin/bash and /bin/sh).

The only thing I can see is the user & group 999 of the .so link, but I don't know if that's relevant. In the worst case I could commit after building, but this seems a bad approach going forward. Any suggestions? Full Dockerfile below:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    curl \ 
    gfortran \
    git \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjasper-dev \
    libjpeg8-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libtiff4-dev \
    libv4l-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python2.7-dev \
    && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoremove && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Get pip and pip installs
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    rm get-pip.py

RUN pip --no-cache-dir --timeout=60 install \
    numpy

# Install opencv and opencv_contrib
WORKDIR /opt/opencv
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git && \
    git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git

WORKDIR /opt/opencv/opencv/build
RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
            -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
            -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules \
            -D CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/nvidia/lib64/libcuda.so \
            -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
RUN make -j8 
RUN make install
```

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I'm having the same issue with no luck fixing...

Comment: No, unfortunately I never got a satisfying solution to this. I think I just committed the working build, and later after various changes (to Dockerfile, nvidia-docker version, etc.) the issue magically went away. Sorry to not be of much help, it's been awhile. [This (much more complicated) Dockerfile](https://github.com/sullivak/cvmldocker/blob/master/dockerfiles/omni/Dockerfile) worked with nvidia-docker 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be